# Unable to get started with Coffeescript on windows

Tags: node.js, coffeescript

I am trying to get coffeescript installed on a windows machine, but am unable to run the coffee command. Here's what I am getting on trying coffee -v on the console:

```
    Program 'coffee' failed to execute: No application is associated with the specified  file for this operation
    At line:1 char:7
    + coffee <<<<  -v.
    At line:1 char:1
    +  <<<< coffee -v
    + CategoryInfo          : ResourceUnavailable: (:) [], ApplicationFailedException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NativeCommandFailed
```

I installed node and tried installing coffeescript both through

```
npm install -g coffee-script@1.1.1
```

as well as

```
npm install -g http://github.com/jashkenas/coffee-script/tarball/master
```

Comment: are you running PowerShell or something ?

Comment: yes, but I have tried it with both powershell as well as standard cmd on windows XP sp3

Comment: never seen that kind of error with cmd.exe. Anyway, it's clearly not coming from coffee

Answer (score 0):

Powershell is not able to determine the interpreter from the top line of script like a unix shell would. The solution is to specify the Node application yourself:

```
node ./node_modules/path/to/coffee
```